Why does factor appear significant in 2-way ANOVA but not by inspection (mean +/- sd or error plot)?
I am puzzled about the result of a 2-way ANOVA analysis. The factors are categorical and non-random and the sum of squares used is constrained type III (the choice of categorical or SS type does not appear to be important to the outcome though).
The data consists of 50 measurements, 2 levels in one factor ("catalyst"), 5 in the other ("chemical treatment"), and 5 replicates per treatment.
The following error plot illustrates mean +/- std dev for the individual treatments, blocked according to factor #2 (catalyst, with two levels, -/+).
(edit: I substituted a boxplot with an error plot; comments further recommend simply a scatter plot. Note I chose to post a boxplot because this is the default visualization provided by MATLAB ANOVA functions; the documentation of these functions explains the meaning of the lines and symbols which may be somewhat unique).

In the above treatments 1-5 and 6-10 correspond to two levels (-/+) of factor #2  (catalyst) whereas treatments 1-5 differ in factor #1 (chemical treatment, with levels matched by 6-10).
It appears from inspection that factor #1 (chemical treatment) has an effect but the same is hard to say for factor #2 (catalyst).
I ran the analysis in MATLAB as
[p,tbl,model] =  anovan(msmnt,{var1,var2},"Model","interaction",'varnames',{'var 1','var 2'}); %Two-Way ANOVA
This is the output table:



Source
Sum Sq.
d.f.
Mean Sq.
F
Prob>F




factor 1  (chem treatment)
612.97
4
153.242
56.86
0


factor 2 (catalyst)
22.445
1
22.445
8.33
0.0063


factor 1:factor 2
12.53
4
3.132
1.16
0.3418


Error
107.8
40
2.695




Total
755.745
49






There appears to be a significant effect (95% confidence) due to both factors (and no interaction).
I computed some of the ANOVA terms by hand and they (well, my computation) seem correct.
However if you look at the means for each of the two levels of factor #2:



fact#2 (catalyst) level
average
sample std dev




-
15.35
4.50


+
16.68
3.34



The error plot (simple inspection) and averages suggest that this is not a significant difference (no effect due to factor #2, catalyst), but the ANOVA table seems to say otherwise.
This conflicting interpretation is confusing. What am I missing in my analysis? Is the ANOVA seeing something I don't?
I suspect the reason is that the within-treatment variances are relatively small. However, if that is true, how do I determine whether the two treatments within individual pairs (eg 1-6, 2-7, etc, differing in presence or absence of catalyst) generate significantly different effects?

This is not a great way to visualize the results because the relatively tiny effect of Factor #2 is swamped by the overall variability.  Since Factor #1 has such a strong effect, consider regressing it out and studying how the residuals vary with Factor #2.  That will (greatly) magnify the ability of the visualization to detect relatively tiny effects.

@whuber thanks, I updated just as you wrote. I suspect that the within-treatment variances are small, but that is not convincing, and even if it allows the difference between pairs to be revealed, how to follow this up with something like a HSD analysis between 1 and 6, 2 and 7 etc. The HSD does not appear to allow this. I might have to edit my post to emphasize this point but I am trying to get oriented.

As far as I can tell, your post is asking why the ANOVA results differ from what you see.  For that to be a meaningful or interesting question, you really need to use an appropriate--and suitably powerful--method of visualizing the data before you can conclude anything.

If you are going to use some kind of parallel boxes, I'd line them up in pairs so that your current 1 is next to your current 5, 2 next to 6 and so on.  Or, better, you could use some sort of trellis plot.

There are 49 total degrees of freedom and 10 boxplots. So 5 points per boxplot. This isn't a great choice. See this: How should we do boxplots with small samples?.

And Minimum "recommended" sample size for boxplots? Boxplots for different sample sizes

@dipetkov thanks, yes this point has been repeated and I realize a boxplot did not make sense to show this data. I have updated to what I hope is something more reasonable.

@whuber thanks again, I see if I plot the treatment data pairwise that there might be a slope due to factor 2 and that's presumably what the ANOVA has picked up, although it does not see an interaction (eg slight negative slope for 4/9). Would it suffice to subtract the group mean for each pair of treatments (grouped by factor #2) to perform the regression you suggest?

Why don't you plot the actual data points? You have 50 points and you can make an effective plot showing all of them. (That's the advice in the CV threads I linked to. If you're not sure how, that's a new question.) It seems that in your current viz you calculate standard errors separately for each treatment but that's not how anova models the data.

@dipetkov Ok, true, I looked at some of the linked posts. ANOVA computes a residual error which I take to be a mean pooled within-treatment error. I guess this to be the sq root of the Error MS term in the table. Would it be better to use this as an "error bar" in the plots instead of the std devs? I am having trouble answering the question of whether there is any added value from including boxplots or other representation (ie mean and std dev for each treatment as in my current answer) as well as the original data points.

I suggest that you ask a new question that's specifically about how to make an informative plot of your data, and specifically how the plot can help to highlight the (potential) effects of the two factors & their interaction. It would greatly help to share your data or a simulation that's very similar to your data. Explain what the factors and the outcome are since it's always more fun to discuss the actual situation that the abstract "factor 1" and "factor 2".

@dipetkov it seems between comments and the answer I received you have answered my main question. The nature of the plot was adding confusion, but thanks for pointing out that I should use another plot. I will simply show medians in addition to the scatter plot. I remain unsure about how to do post-hoc significance test to check for which pairs (eg 1 and 6) there is a significant difference due to factor #2. I will try to edit my post somewhat although I think I already mauled it by removing reference to boxplots and should roll back.

Take a look at the [tag:contrasts] tag.

When you take the simple means of the DV by factor level, you are not controlling for the other variable. With ANOVA, you are. You would have to look at the means of the two levels of that factor for each of the five levels of the other. (It would have made this easier to write if you had told us what these factors are).
This is like comparing 1 to 5, 2 to 6, 3 to 7, and so on in the plot. Also, that's not a usual boxplot. I did a very little bit of Googling and did not find one like it. It's a little like a violin plot. But what are the extra lines?

Matlab details boxplots here (see the "more about" section).

"It would have made this easier to write if you had told us what these factors are". For factor#1 there are 5 levels (eg treatments 1-5 differ in this factor) , it is categorical. The boxplot shows the means +/- sd (and percentiles) for each treatment (corresponding to combination of factors 1 and 2): there are 2x5 possible treatments.

I am confident Peter is not asking what a boxplot is.  One of the (many) problems with the plots in the question is that they do not clearly reveal the two-factor structure of the analysis (nor do they help at all with the interaction).  The use of confidence bands for boxplots that represent only 5 values each is unnecessary and visually confusing, too. (Typically there are more graphical elements in each box then there are data behind it!)  You could do much better plotting the data themselves on dot plots.

@whuber I apologize, that would be a limitation with my present abilities with Matlab. While a little painful it is not difficult to perform a visual analysis. As mentioned, 1 and 6 differ in level of 2-level categorical factor #2 but are at the same level of categorical factor #1. Similarly 2-7,3-8,4-9,5-10 are paired wrt factor #1.

First, yes, I know what a box plot is. The notches are clear enough, too (notched box plot) but there are a bunch of extra lines. They are not explained and nothing in the 'more about" section has them.
And you still haven't said what the factors are -- e.g. they might be sex and race; or political party and age group; or who knows what.

The levels of factor #1 are different chemical reagents applied to equivalent substrates. For factor #2 these are orthogonal to factor #1 (presumed to be non-interacting) and can be assumed to be 2 different solvents.

The more about section does provide quite a bit of information. Plus marks (+) are outliers, for instance, dashed lines are whiskers.

Yes, I know that. But look at YOUR plot. It has more lines than that.

I suspect the "extra lines" you refer to are the "notches". From the documentation: "Notches display the variability of the median between samples. The width of a notch is computed so that boxes whose notches do not overlap have different medians at the 5% significance level. The significance level is based on a normal distribution assumption, but comparisons of medians are reasonably robust for other distributions. Comparing box plot medians is like a visual hypothesis test, analogous to the t test used for means. In some cases, notches can extend outside the boxes."

Thanks for your answer. Upon review it seems showing boxplots was a mistake. I picked this somewhat out of convenience (it is the default display method in Matlab when performing ANOVA). A scatter plot  would have been better as whuber and dipetkov pointed out. Your answer though does answer my actual question, and whuber pointed out why I missed the obvious. Factor #1 has a strong effect and #2 weak (I suspected none but the ANOVA identified one).

I'd like to avoid posting a new question, but my remaining uncertainty is how to perform pairwise comparisons to see where differences due to factor #2 are significant (eg between 1 and 6). Is this at all possible? I can edit my original post and try not to alter it too much.

Because Peter's post here doesn't answer your original question -- it plays the role of an extended request for clarification -- I would suggest modifying your question here rather than starting a new thread.

@whuber To be fair I was stumbling a bit in the dark. The MATLAB documentation is not great. In general the statistics package  hides the computations being performed (R code is not much better but the documentation is; I realize a more advanced textbook might include relevant details). This also got wrapped up in discussion of plots (which was useful). The small effect of factor 2 is obfuscated by the presentation, as this answer points out. A comment suggested I read up on contrasts. I edited to clarify the q: how to determine significance of fact #2, including within individual pairs.

Agreed about the Matlab docs.  But my experience with their tech support has been great -- and in all the cases I was investigating (which included fairly low-level code), it was possible to read the source code and to put hooks into it to monitor what it was doing.  But using general-purpose tools like Matlab, Mathematica, etc., for statistical analysis is IMHO best done when you know in detail what you're doing, which means (among other things) having long experience with and access to at least one dedicated statistical analysis platform.
